# Python numbers bruteforcing

Tags: python, brute-force

I'm trying to make a brute-force algorithm.
I would print all possible combinations of numbers between 00000000 (8 numbers) and 999999999999 (12 numbers)

I've found this code:

```
for c in itertools.product(numbers, repeat=12):
    pin = y+''.join(c)
    print(pin)
```

But using this code I can't set a minimum length, so it starts by 000000000000(12 numbers)

Any ideas?

Comment: you're asking to print around 1 trillion value. Not over a thousand years...

Comment: Have you even considered looking at that repeat argument that seems to be set to 12?

Comment: Come on, no bashing around here :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Maybe with `numbers = '0123456789'`.  But you could also set `numbers = '0123'`.  Maybe we are talking about a combination lock with four possible values for each dial.

Comment: I know, I'm just learning this programming language, I don't want seriously make a bruteforce like this!

Comment: in that case, don't use too many digits

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers = '01'  # you could use '0123456789' but that would take very long
y = 'foo'

for length in range(8, 13):
  for c in itertools.product(numbers, repeat=length):
    pin = y+''.join(c)
    print(pin)
```

Comment: tell your grandchildren not to close the window until year 2500, though. there's a reason why they use 12-digit codes: it's because it's very long to bruteforce them.

Comment: Nice solution, but why not use a list comprehension: pin = [str(r).zfill(12) for r in range(1E12)]?

Comment: @Alfe your duty is to warn the user that it's stupid to do this at least with those values.

Comment: @tnknepp because you need around 10 terabytes to store the data. but your solution is even better than the `product` one (if we decrease the 10**12 constraint)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Otherwise a perfectly sound solution ;)  Of course, by the time the list is populated 10TB of RAM will be considered small.

Comment: @tnknepp yes, if you can add extra ram while it's running :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Instead of what you proposed (I commented on your idea in the comments to the Q already) I set useful values for the variables to have a quickly finishing program.

Comment: @tnknepp Clearly a comprehension has two main disadvantages here:  ① OP is obviously not very experienced, so putting that kind of cognitive load onto him is not helping.  ② A generating algorithm attached to a consuming one (instead of a storing one) is generally preferable if you want to process a huge amount of values.  You could, however, use a generator comprehension: `(c for length in range(8, 13) for c in itertools.product(numbers, repeat=length))`, but there's still reason ①.